# How to instantiate a Spark Dataset<Row> Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have not found anything on the Spark website, SO, or google.
I have a service that sets and gets a Dataset created by another class, i.e.

```
public class MainFrameServiceImpl implements MainFrameService {
    private Dataset<Row> queryDF = null;
    public MainFrameServiceImpl() {
//this.queryDF <--need to instantiate this

    }
    public void setDataset(Dataset<Row> queryDF) {
        this.queryDF = queryDF;
    }
    public Dataset<Row> getDataset() {
        return this.queryDF;
    }

}
```

But I do cannot return the Dataset unless its instantiated. When I try, which I know shouldn't work I get the error

> at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:189)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)

Basically, I want to pass a Dataset between different classes and operate on them for a GUI. 
If there is another way to pass the information without spark coming out of lazy-evaluation, I am open to all suggestions.

I have tried creating a method in the service that reads the passed Dataset and instantiates the class Dataset, but this doesn't work.
example:

```
public void setDatasetStruct(Dataset<Row> queryDF) {
        ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(queryDF.schema());
        this.queryDF = new Dataset<Row>(SparkManager.getSession(), queryDF.queryExecution().logical(), encoder);
        setDataset(queryDF);
    }

    public void setDataset(Dataset<Row> queryDF) {
        this.queryDF = queryDF;
    }
```